# Create a Document object, run JavaScript in it, and get final HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

```
let html = '<body><p id="a"></p><script>document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "hello"</script></body>'
let doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('')
doc.open()
doc.write(html)
doc.close()
doc.getElementById('a').innerHTML // expecting "hello" but get an empty string instead
```

The HTML document created by `document.implementation.createHTMLDocument` doesn't seem to run JavaScript inside it.

Comment: no you can't run javascript in fragment documents, use an iframe (you'll have to append it in the main document)

Comment: check the browser compatibility. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createHTMLDocument

Answer (score 0):

check this simple method which can work for you.

```
let html = '<body><p id="a"></p><script>document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "hello"</scr'+'ipt></body>';
        document.open();
        document.write(html);
        document.close();
```

Comment: Ohh let me find other solution , will get back to you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kaiido's comment. The following code works the way I want:

```
let html = '<body><p id="a"></p><script>document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "hello"</script></body>'
let iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
iframe.style.display = 'none'
document.body.appendChild(iframe)
let doc = iframe.contentWindow.document
doc.open()
doc.write(html)
doc.close()
doc.getElementById('a').innerHTML
```

Comment: I think I remember that some browsers won't load the content of an iframe with `display: none`, be careful, and you may want to set your iframe's `width` and `height` to  0 and to push it off-screen instead. Also, you forgot to escape your `</script>` ending tag declaration in the `html` string. I guess you fixed it on your side, otherwise, the script would have stopped here with a nice "unterminated string literal" error. (it should be `<\/script>`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! The code above works fine in Chrome, which is good enough for my use case.